# Stable and Unstable Horocycle Flows of the Unit Tangent Bunble $\mathrm{T^1}\mathbb{H}$ of $\mathbb{H}$

Tags: matrices, manifolds, group-actions, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

**Ergodic Theory with a view towards Number Theory**, Chapter **9**, Page **287**, **288**.

Let $$\mathbb{H}=\{x+iy \in \mathbb{C}, y>0\}$$ and $\mathrm{T^1}\mathbb{H}$ be the unit tangent bundle of $\mathbb{H}$.
[image]

I would like to enquire whether **Stable Horocycle Flows** (**Unstable Horocycle Flows**) is the **Positive** (**Negative**) Horocycle Flows or the **Negative** (**Positive**) one.

Comment: I'm curious - what are stable/unstable/positive/negative horocycle flows?

Comment: @runway44 take a look at the question again, I have just edited it.

Comment: Well, the text is using a minus sign to denote stable horocycle flow, and positive sign to denote unstable horocycle flow. Did you just post an image answering your own question?

Comment: @runway44 the problem is that in any book there is not minus sign inside brackets, so $u^+(s)$ not $u^+(-s)$ and $u^-(s)$ not $u^-(-s)$. Why did he add these minus signs?

Comment: I don't know why he assigned positive to unstable and negative to stable. My best guess is that it is then in analogy with exponential growth, where the graph diverges to $\infty$ in the positive reals but converges to $0$ in the negative reals. But whatever the reason, it makes sense to use two different notations for two different actions (one-parameter subgroups). You surely can't simply put a minus sign *inside* the parentheses, that would just be wrong; it should be clear that $$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \pm s \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \ne \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ \pm s & 1 \end{bmatrix}. $$

Comment: @runway44 I meant, in many other references, we have $hu^-(s)$ not $hu^-(-s)$ and $hu^+(s)$ not $hu^+(-s)$.

Comment: Ah, that part. I think the author is making a mistake there. If $(z,v)=Dg(i,i)$ then we should be using $D(g\circ u\circ g^{-1})$ on $(z,v)$, which is equivalent to $D(g\circ u)$ on $(i,i)$, so there shouldn't be a $-s$. My best guess for the mistake was maybe the author mixed up $g^{-1}$ with $u^{-1}$ (the inverse). If that was your question the whole time, you shouldn't have waited a whole day and multiple comments to finally reveal it! Just put your actual question in your question to begin with!